# Moving average 2 day span using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a dataframe, df, that I would like to calculate the moving average for the next 2 days, with a window of 5. I then wish to store the results in a variable within Python:

```
 date                count

 08052020            50
 08152020            10
 08252020            30
 09052020            10
 09152020            15
 09252020            5
```

This is what I am doing:

```
 count = df['new'] = df['count'].rolling(2).mean()
 print(count)
```

Any insight is appreciated.

*Updated* Desired output:

```
 count = [23, 14]
```

Comment: You said you want moving avg for next 2 days and you're using 5 in `rolling`. And please elaborate how you got desired output(formula you're using).  If you take moving avg with window of 5 values should be 23 and 14

Comment: Let me update post please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df['new'] = df['count'].rolling(5).mean()

count = df["new"].dropna().to_list()

print(count)
```

Output:

```
[23.0, 14.0]
```

Comment: Ok thanks @Sociopath   How would I specify the number of days or periods I wish to ‘forecast’? I was thinking I have to specify this in the rolling function?

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the concept, you can not *forecast* the moving averages, Moving avgs are just avg over certain time window. Currenly we're using 5 values to calculate the moving avg.  It can be used as features for forecasting but forecasting moving avg doesn't make sense to me